# Dose additional dot in the domain is a valid domain

Tags: linux, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

we want to build a new hadoop cluster ( ambari cluster ) , on redhat Linux machiens

our host-names are

```
master01.fg.sys70.com
master02.fg.sys70.com
master03.fg.sys70.com
worker01.fg.sys70.com
worker02.fg.sys70.com
worker03.fg.sys70.com
```

dose the additional "." in domain could be problematic when building a new hadoop cluster?

Comment: I never used Hadoop so I can't put the finger on this comment and say this will be a problem, but generally, domains can only have two dots. Any more than that, it will confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently maintain Hadoop servers that are named per environment

For example

```
ambari.test.domain.com
```

It works fine as long as your DNS services can resolve the addresses

---

I suggest not calling something just `master` when building a cluster... Master of what? There's so many master services (Ambari Server, Namenode, HiveServer, ResourceManager, HBase Master, etc). If you have the available hardware, split each Hadoop service to individual machines and name them appropriately to that service.

If something is only a datanode and nodemanager, feel free to name it "worker"

Comment: you said that you success to install HDP cluster with domain name - test.domain.com , could you please give yours HDP version ?

Comment: when we installed the blueprint we got the error from API -  "message" : "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid transition for servicecomponenthost,

Comment: It's been through several upgrades from HDP 2.2 to 2.5.3

Comment: We didn't use blueprints

Answer (score 0):

No this should not be a problem, I have installed numerous Hadoop clusters, one this to double check is that forward and reverse DNS work correctly.